# Postgresql non distinct pairs across multiple columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to return records from a table in postgresql that when a distinct value in column 1 has more then one different values in column 2 spread over multiple records.

As a simple example:

table1:

```
column1 - column2
1 – 1
1 – 2
2 – 1
2 – 1 
3 - 3
4 - 5
```

return:

```
1 - 1
1 - 2
```

There is a lot of examples showing distinct (such as this), but I'm looking for non distinct.

```
select distinct (column2, column1) my_distinct from table1;
```

Comment: If it does not have to be very efficient just do two nested `GROUP BY` - `COUNT` queries.

Comment: ... or wrap your `distict` query into `GROUP BY` - `COUNT` one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a vanilla way to do it. Just an exists to check for records where there is a different value on column2 for the same column1.

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/Zf9vTS9K

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  column1 INTEGER,
  column2 INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO t
  (column1, column2)
VALUES
  (1, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (2, 1),
  (2, 1),
  (3, 3),
  (4, 5);

select * 
  from t t1
 where exists
         (
           select 1
             from t t2
            where t1.column1 = t2.column1
              and t1.column2 <> t2.column2
         );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE to get all the values of `column1` you're looking for, then filter the table:

**Schema (PostgreSQL v15)**

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  column1 INTEGER,
  column2 INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO t
  (column1, column2)
VALUES
  (1, 1),
  (1, 2),
  (2, 1),
  (2, 1),
  (3, 3),
  (4, 5);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT column1
  FROM t
  GROUP BY 1
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT column2) > 1
)
SELECT column1, column2
FROM t
JOIN cte USING (column1);
```

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

---

Alternatively you can create a list of the `column2` values (per column1) and unnest that, which avoids scanning the table a second time.

**Query #2**

```
SELECT column1, unnest(array_agg(column2)) AS column2
FROM t
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT column2) > 1;
```

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bjcjmvXmApVXq7ndpFyxru/1)

Comment: You don't even need the CTE, you can write `...unnest(array_agg(column2)) AS column2...` in the query you actually use in your CTE.

Comment: Oh yeah. Nice one, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**You should use window functions** for this, it is likely far more efficient than joins.

Unfortunately, `COUNT(DISTINCT` is not implemented for window functions, so you need to hack it with `DENSE_RANK` and `MAX`

```sql
with ranked as (
    select *,
      dense_rank() over (partition by column1 order by column2) as dr 
    from t
),
maxed as (
    select *,
      max(dr) over (partition by column1) as max_dr
    from ranked
)
select
  column1,
  column2
from maxed
where max_dr > 1;
```

Another option in your specific case is to compare counts with two different partitionings.

The idea is that if there are more rows in the partitioning just by `column1` than by `column1` *and* `column2` then there must exist at least two distinct `column2` values.

- If there is exactly one row in the `column1` partition then both return `1`.
- If there are multiple identical rows in it then both return the same value again.
- If there is are multiple `column2` values, whether duplicated or not, then the overall partitioning will return a higher value than the `column2` partitioning.

```sql
with counted as (
    select *,
      count(*) over (partition by column1, column2) as c1,
      count(*) over (partition by column1) as c2
    from t
)
select
  column1,
  column2
from counted
where c1 < c2;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/fHA_MrGZ)